How to Print Multiple Images with CUPS
We implemented printing using CUPS code on Android.
The code below prints one image file by transferring it to the printer.
#include "cups/cups.h"
#include "score_printing.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int scorePrint(char* printerName, char* priterUri, char* mimeType, char* filePath){
    cups_dest_t* pDest;
    http_t* pHttp;
    cups_dinfo_t* pInfo;
    int nOptions = 0;
    cups_option_t* pOptions = NULL;
    int nJobId = 0;
    ipp_status_t status = IPP_OK;
    size_t bytes;
    int loop = 0;
    FILE* pOut = NULL;
    char buffer[65536];
    char resource[256];


    cupsSetEncryption(HTTP_ENCRYPTION_REQUIRED);

    pDest = cupsGetDestWithURI(printerName, priterUri);

    if(pDest == NULL){
      printf("pDest is NULL");
    }else{
      printf("pDest is not NULL");
    }

    pHttp = cupsConnectDest(pDest, CUPS_DEST_FLAGS_DEVICE, 10000, NULL, resource, sizeof(resource), NULL, NULL);

    if (pHttp == NULL) {
      printf("printer not connect");
    }else{
      printf("printer connect");
    }

     if ((pInfo = cupsCopyDestInfo(pHttp, pDest)) == NULL) {
       printf("Get printer info failed");
     }else{
       printf("Get printer info success");
     }

     nOptions = cupsAddOption(CUPS_COPIES, "1", nOptions, &pOptions);
     nOptions = cupsAddOption(CUPS_MEDIA, CUPS_MEDIA_A4, nOptions, &pOptions);
     nOptions = cupsAddOption(CUPS_ORIENTATION, CUPS_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT, nOptions, &pOptions);

     status = cupsCreateDestJob(pHttp, pDest, pInfo, &nJobId, "My Document", nOptions, pOptions);

     if (status != IPP_OK || nJobId == 0)
     {
       printf("printer Job failed : %x, %d", status, nJobId);
     }else{
       printf("printer Job success");
     }

       printf("printing start : %d", loop);
       pOut = fopen(filePath, "rb");

       if (cupsStartDestDocument(pHttp, pDest, pInfo, nJobId, filePath, mimeType, 0, NULL, 1) == HTTP_STATUS_CONTINUE)
     {
       while ((bytes = fread(buffer, 1, sizeof(buffer), pOut)) > 0)
       {
         if (cupsWriteRequestData(pHttp, buffer, bytes) != HTTP_STATUS_CONTINUE)
           break;
       }
       if (cupsFinishDestDocument(pHttp, pDest, pInfo) != IPP_STATUS_OK)
       {
         printf("Document send failed: %s", cupsLastErrorString());
       }
       else{
         printf("Document send success: %s", cupsLastErrorString());
       }
     }

     fclose(pOut);

     cupsFreeDests(1, pDest);
     cupsFreeDestInfo(pInfo);
     cupsFreeOptions(nOptions, pOptions);
     httpClose(pHttp);

     return 1;
}

If you call the above code, the image will be output from the printer normally. (However, printers that support the mimetype of image/jpeg)
Now I want to print multiple images. For example, let's say you want to print three images.
char* szPrinterName = "my_printer_name";
char* szPrinterURL = "ipp://my_printer_url/ipp/print"
char* szFilePath = "my_printing_image_path";

for (int i=0; i<3; i++) {
  scorePrint(szPrinterName, szPrinterURL, CUPS_FORMAT_JPEG, szFilePath);
}

Here's where the problem arises.
One page (the first page) is printed normally, but the second page is not printed as error 507 (server-error-busy) occurs and JobID creation fails.
Do you know the solution??
